# AJAX update post_meta not updating the_modified_date

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Wondering if someone knows a way to trigger an update to `the_modified_date` of a post when using AJAX to change `post_meta`?

I believe that this is caused because there is no `add_action( 'save_post'` passed in the AJAX and is only updating the DB directly.

Can this be done via JS or is it a question of adding to the PHP function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to change your post **modified date**, then you need to update *the post*, not *post meta*.

I'm sending you simple example how to do that, and for sure that is on the php realm, either in `functions.php` file or inside your custom plugin file. X is the post number (integer)

```
$post = array(
    'post_modified'  => date(), 
    'post_modified_gmt'   => date(), 
    'ID'          => X, // $post->ID;
);
// update post
wp_update_post( $post );
```

You can change your date via `ajax` for sure, but for that you need to use use native WP `wp_ajax_(action)` hook and a little javascript(jQuery).. take a look here for more info: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)

---

Your question is very vague and can lead to so many directions that we as community can't possibly know what you really want.. You should post questions that are [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) but if you can't then you should share as much code with us as you can!

OK, I'm gonna hope that maybe, this can be of help to someone who finds it via search engines in the future.

Comment: This was perfect @Kresimir Pendic. Thank you for your help.